# Creating a new form with the same z-order as another form

Tags: windows, winforms

Windows Forms, .net 2.0

My main application thread has a form (A).  I have a background thread which operates off a timer to determine that an activity has taken place - when it does, it causes the main application form to hide (using BeginInvoke), and creates a new form (B) in its own thread (seperate message pump).

The two threads thing sounds complicated, but it is needed unfortunately.

The new form, on the new message pump is shown at the top of the non-topmost forms (as you would expect!).  However, if the original application wasn't on top of the desktop this is very annoying.

So, I would like to determine what the z-order of the original form (A) is before hiding it; then create my new form (B) mirroring the z-order of the original form.

Any ideas?

[This also has the side effect of form B popping up over a screen-saver if it is on the current users desktop (ie non passworded), which if I can't fix it how I would like above, I would like to avoid this...]

Comment: I'm curious to hear your reasoning behind having the second form on it's own thread.  I've seen countless times where developers are convinced they need to "multi-thread" their forms until someone asks them to explain why and they can't.  I'm not saying there isn't a case for it, but more often than not the user has the wrong approach.

Comment: The main thread is a complicated LOB application which contains many forms, sub-forms, etc. The second thread is a security procedure which "locks" the main application by hiding all forms, including current dialog boxes, which it can restore later. Some of these forms are created by third party libraries not in our control. If the security requirement had been present since the first day of design, the second application pump may not have been necessary, but it does mean that the lock is "generic" enough to handle third-party forms etc

Comment: Have you tried bringing the dialog forward using .ShowDialog(Me) or .ShowDialog(this).  Using ShowDialog with a reference to the parent will lock the parent form from any input and prevent focus from being allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using the Win32 GetWindow function to determine which the previous window was for my main form.  Then when I create my new form on the second thread I can use SetWindowPos to set the z-order to the value that I obtained in the first step.

I also use nobugz suggestion to determine if the application was the focused application, and if not I use the ShowWithoutActivation override to ensure that my new form does not start activated

Comment: It seems that nobugz answer has been deleted and so this answer doesn't help that much :-(

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can call Form.Activate() to bring it to the front, but I don't know of a Windows-level z-order in WinForms.  You may have better luck in Win32.

Comment: Yep, I don't want to bring it to the front - that's the point.  I rather assumed I would need to p/invoke something from Win32 but I don't know what...